# Why do we use low frequency with copper wires and high frequency with air and optical fibers?

Tags: frequency, bandwidth

1. The bandwidth of twisted pair copper wire is low. Why can low frequencies propagate longer distances through copper wires than high frequencies? On the other hand, high frequencies can propagate long distances through air and optical fibers.
2. Is the bandwidth distance product formula applicable to air, or just to wired transmission such as copper wire and optical fiber?
3. How is the bandwidth distance constant calculated for each medium? If the bandwidth is regulated across the different systems, then what distance is used to calculate the bandwidth-distance constant?

Comment: Can't answer completely but look into wave guides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A twisted pair (or a coax cable for that matter) can be viewed either as a wire, or as a two-conductor waveguide supporting the TEM mode, and ideally only the TEM mode. When the frequency reaches the cutoff frequency \$f_c\$ of the first spurious mode, then the cable begins experiencing severe dispersion since multiple modes of different group velocities are now propagating down the waveguide.

   Likewise, the manufacturing tolerances of twisted pair cable play a role; the kinds of mechanical imperfections that we expect on a typical twisted pair due to manufacturing, bending, etc become fairly severe for high frequencies. If the wavelength of the signal (as guided on the twisted pair) comes close to the mechanical pitch of the twist, then the twisted pair also loses a lot of its benefits w.r.t. rejection of external fields.
2. The bandwidth distance product relates to dispersion, i.e. frequency-dependent group delay. To the best of my knowledge, un-ionized air does not encounter much of this issue, although signals passing through the ionosphere may encounter [ionospheric dispersion](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog862/node/1715).
3. The bandwidth-distance product is a figure of merit for optical communication systems, and is highly dependent on the actual physical properties of the fiber and the choice of modulation scheme. It is very likely an empirical measurement taken from experimentation on a fiber system (or simulation, if the precise dispersive properties are known).

Answer (score 0):

> The bandwidth of twisted pair copper wire is low.

Well I wouldn't say that per se; just that it's lower than optical.  300-baud modems... now those were slow!

> Why can low frequencies propagate longer distances through copper wires than high frequencies?

The reason why is due to parasitic capacitance and inductance.  Each unit length of conductor + insulator introduces small amounts of capacitance and inductance, which work together to limit the possible transition speed.

Most metals are great conductors, so can couple a signal a very long distance. But as the distance increases, so does the parasitics, which limit the max speed.  Er. go., long distances can handle low speeds just fine, and probably at a lower loss than other means.

Optical has neither of these parasitics, but of course has other fundamental (and physical) limits.  Such as emitter modulation speed, refraction/reflection/adsorption coefficients, etc.